# Fiction Book About Knights and Underground Creatures

Tags: story-identification, medieval, undead

Here's what I can recall

- There's a village in a valley and all the houses are built on stone slabs to stop underground creatures from digging up into the houses
- The creatures come out at night and when the villages knights die they are buried under stone piles called cairns, but somehow revive as the underground creatures
- The society is very much medieval in nature, and at the end of the book the villagers allude to venturing outside the valley and looking for other villages, since they couldn't travel much due to the creatures attacking at night.
- I don't remember any details about the author or cover, it was a novel I picked up from my local library's obscure book bin around 2018. The novel could have been much older for all of know
- In the book one of the knights recounts how long ago all the famous knights of the time battled the creatures on a giant rock and vanquished them, but the creatures seem to come back which is later found out to be reanimated villagers

Comment: Consider having a look at the [_Tips for asking Story Identification questions_](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/40711) and [adding](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/279688/edit) other details to your question to improve the chance someone is able to answer.